# IQueryable<T> Join with Where Condition Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to use where condition with `IQueryable<T>` Join approach but find no resources to give me clue how how to filter records based on child table field.

e.g Normal query that I want to execute via `IQueryable<T>` Linq Statement:

```
Select 
    m.* 
from 
    vsk_media as m 
inner join 
    vsk_media_album as v 
on 
    m.id=v.mediaid 
where 
    v.albumid=47
```

Here is my code which works well without where statement:

```
IQueryable<vsk_media> Query = entities.vsk_media;
       Query.Join(entities.vsk_media_albums
       , c => c.id
       , cm => cm.mediaid
       , (c, cm) => new { c, cm });
```

Now how to add where condition to match with child table `vsk_media_albums` (where v.albumid=47) in above IQueryable Statement.

I tried my best to find solution but not found any good resource in web. I am not interested in normal Linq Statement.

Comment: What is a "normal linq statement" and why are you not interested in it?

Comment: just append `.Where(e=>e.cm.albumid == 47)` at the end of your query.

Comment: and then a `Select(x => x.c)` I guess if he only wants the vsk_media entity.

Comment: normal linq like "from m in entities.vsk_media join ... where v.albumid=47 but due to my project requirement i prefer to use IQuerable<T> statement.

Comment: @DavidG yes, I've just spotted out that :)

Comment: @irfanmcsd You do realise that it's exactly the same thing, just effectively different syntax?

Comment: @Hopeless it works i think :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try this using extension methods:

```
var query = entities.vsk_media
                    .Join(entities.vsk_media_album, 
                          m => m.id,
                          v => v.mediaid,
                          (m, v) => new { m, v })
                    .Where(x => x.v.albumid == 47)
                    .Select(x => x.m);

var list = query.ToList();
```

Or using the linq structure:

```
var query = from m in entities.vsk_media
            join v in entities.vsk_media_album on m.id equals v.mediaid
            where v.albumid = 47
            select m;

var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks but same thing i want with IQueryable<T> Join statement

Answer (score 4):

I know this has already been answered, but you should have navigations properties set up on vsk_media, then you can do this (assuming you navigation property from media to media_album is called "Albums"):

```
var list = entities.vsk_media
  .Include(m=>m.Albums)
  .Where(m=>m.Albums.albumid==47);
```

If you don't need the album info beyond just filtering based on it, then you can do this:

```
var list = entities.vsk_media
  .Where(m=>m.Albums.albumid==47);
```

Comment: thanks it will be helpful. currently just need for where operation.

Comment: "just need for where operation", so you never need to reference a vsk_media's albums, or an album's media, and you never join those two tables except for this one place?